# Where do I see the HTML logs?

Tags: docker, sitespeedio

If I run sitespeed within a docker and obtain the following output:

```
Google Chrome 63.0.3239.84
Mozilla Firefox 54.0.1
[2017-12-27 18:10:01] INFO: Versions OS: linux 4.9.49-moby nodejs: v8.9.1 sitespeed.io: 6.2.2 browsertime: 2.1.2 coach: 1.1.1
[2017-12-27 18:10:02] INFO: Starting chrome for analysing https://www.google.com/ 3 time(s)
[2017-12-27 18:10:02] INFO: Testing url https://www.google.com/ run 1
[2017-12-27 18:10:18] INFO: Testing url https://www.google.com/ run 2
[2017-12-27 18:10:29] INFO: Testing url https://www.google.com/ run 3
[2017-12-27 18:10:40] INFO: 18 requests, 584.40 kb, backEndTime: 158ms (±6.42ms), firstPaint: 321ms (±3.32ms), firstVisualChange: 389ms (±7.78ms), DOMContentLoaded: 376ms (±3.63ms), Load: 529ms (±91.22ms), speedIndex: 477 (±9.23), visualComplete85: 422ms (±7.90ms), lastVisualChange: 2.65s (±137.82ms), rumSpeedIndex: 321 (±3.32) (3 runs)
[2017-12-27 18:10:43] INFO: HTML stored in /sitespeed.io/reports
[2017-12-27 18:10:43] INFO: Finished analysing https://www.google.com/
```

Where are the HTML logs stored? '/sitespeed.io/reports', I'm not sure where to go to access this.

Comment: Can you add your `docker run ...` command? For example, the [docs](https://hub.docker.com/r/sitespeedio/sitespeed.io/) mention that by adding `--rm -v "$(pwd)":/sitespeed.io` the result HTML will be stored on your host's filesystem. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example from the [Docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/sitespeedio/sitespeed.io/) page says:

```
docker run --shm-size=1g --rm -v "$(pwd)":/sitespeed.io sitespeedio/sitespeed.io http://www.sitespeed.io/ -b chrome
```

- the `--rm` part of the command means that the container is removed after it finishes. So you will not be able to get "inside" the container and access the results, but...
- the `-v "$(pwd)":/sitespeed.io` part means that

  - `-v`: a `volume` is created
  - `"$(pwd)"`: at your working directory
  - pointing to the `/sitespeed.io` folder of the container

---

Practically this means that if you run the above command at a directory named `/my-docker-tests`, (despite of the fact that the container is removed) you will be able to see the result files on your host's file system at `/my-docker-tests/sitespeed-result/`

[image]